# Next.js: React Apollo Client Not sending cookies?

Tags: express, graphql, next.js, apollo, server-side-rendering

I'm using Apollo Client as a `graphql` client on my `next.js` application, Here is the function that creates a client for me:

```
let client: ApolloClient<any>;

export const __ssrMode__: boolean = typeof window === "undefined";
export const uri: string = "http://localhost:3001/graphql";

const createApolloClient = (): ApolloClient<any> => {
  return new ApolloClient({
    credentials: "include",
    ssrMode: __ssrMode__,
    link: createHttpLink({
      uri,
      credentials: "include",
    }),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });
};
```

Surprisingly, when I make a mutation to the graphql server I'm able to set the cookies but, I'm not able to get the cookies from the client. What may be possibily the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I came to the same problem, my solution was to create a client every time a server-side rendering is made, maybe it's not ideal to have a client to execute GraphQL calls in the browser and others in the server but it's what worked best for me. This is the code:

```js
import { ApolloClient, createHttpLink, InMemoryCache } from '@apollo/client';
import { NextPageContext } from 'next';
import { setContext } from '@apollo/client/link/context';

export const httpLink = createHttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql',
  credentials: 'include',
});

const CreateClient = (ctx: NextPageContext | null) => {
  const authLink = setContext((_, { headers }) => {
    return {
      headers: {
        ...headers,
        cookie:
          (typeof window === 'undefined'
            ? ctx?.req?.headers.cookie || undefined
            : undefined) || '',
      },
    };
  });

  return new ApolloClient({
    credentials: 'include',
    link: authLink.concat(httpLink),
    cache: new InMemoryCache(),
    ssrMode: true,
  });
};

export default CreateClient;
```

So, what I do is pass the context from the **getServerSideProps** and see if I have some cookies there, if so I just set the cookies, you can also send the authorization token if it's in the cookie. To call it is very simple:

```js
export async function getServerSideProps(context: NextPageContext) {
  const client = CreateClient(context);

  const { data } = await client.query({
    query: SOME_QUERY,
  });

  return {
    props: {
      data,
    },
  };
}
```

You can also do a HOC as in the Ben Awad tutorial [Apollo Client HOC](https://github.com/benawad/lireddit/blob/master/web/src/utils/withApollo.ts) but I think it was too much for what I was trying to do. Hope it helped you or helps someone there :)

Also, I'm using Next 12.1.5 and React 18

Comment: Thank you Jesuspinarte. Have been struggling with this for hours. Your solution worked.